# Schtasks CMD .bat trouble

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-task-scheduler

When i run the task it starts the .exe fine but the event ID isn't triggering the .exe automatically.

```
@echo off
@SCHTASKS /Create /TN Security_Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing_4624 /TR "C:\Program Files (x86)\example.exe" /SC ONEVENT /EC Security /MO "*[Security[(EventID=4624)]]" /f
@exit
:h
goto h
```

(This is saved to notepad as a .bat and run as administrator)

Comment: Try `/MO *[Security/EventId=4624]`.  It's been a while since I supported Windows TaskScheduler.

Comment: That still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure that event Id has been fired?

Comment: You trying to run this as the currently logged on user.  What does your program actually do?

Comment: Also, how are you testing this?

Comment: It isn't the actual event ID im working with. The .exe is a python alert program I coded. When I right click in event log and assign an ID to run a program it runs fine. But when I run the .bat it shows up as a task and when running does run the .py file but doesn't run when the event ID is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use the wizard, in Event Viewer, to bind a task to the event, start `Computer Management => Task Scheduler` and drill down to `Task Scheduler Library => Event Viewer Tasks`, find the task named `Security_Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing_4624` and export it to XML.

At this point you can simply include that XML file with your script and modify the script to import the XML task description on the system.  Optionally, you can compare that XML file with one exported from the task you created using the CLI, to see the differences.  The differences in `Subscription` content of the `EventTrigger` node will be instructive.